# how to create AzureML environment from a pip requirements file

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am very comfortable with creating environment from a requirements file using pip. Could i create the same type of environment from requirements file for AzureML experiment?

Answer (score -1):

First we have to create a requirements file and store it in directory in AzureML workspace directory.

```
myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(name="myenv", file_path="path-to-pip-requirements-file")
```

Then, we can use it for our experiment.

For example:

```
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=".",
                      script="example.py",
                      compute_target="local",
                      environment=myenv)

run = myexp.submit(config=src)

run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```